# inserting HTML in json causing error (unexpected end of string)

Tags: html, json

I am trying to insert a snippet of HTML into my JSON file and it gives me an error that unexpected end of string. I found out that you have to add backslash before and after double quotes to solve the issue and implement HTML within JSON but it did not solve the issue for me. What is the correct way to integrate HTML in one's JSON code? how can i fix this?
Here is my code snippet:

```
enter code here
     {            
       "splash": {
                "splashContent": "<div style=\"text-align: justify;\">
                <h2><b><u><span style=\"color:windowtext;mso-ansi-language:EN-US\">Theoretical
                background:<o:p></o:p></span></u></b>
                </h2>
                
                <h2><span style=\"font-weight: normal;\"><font size=\"3\"><span style=\"mso-ansi-language:EN-US\">In this area of the application,
                you can find a comparison between the predicted air pollutant concentration values
                of the CITYCHEM model’s forecast and real measurement data from the city of
                Hamburg.</span></font></span></h2><h2><span style=\"font-weight: normal;\"><font size=\"3\"><span style=\"mso-ansi-language:EN-US\"><br /> </span><span style=\"mso-ansi-language:EN-US\">There are fifteen
                active measurement stations located in Hamburg, which measure O<sub>3</sub>,
                PM10, NO<sub>2</sub> and <span style=\"color:black;mso-themecolor:text1\">NO. </span></span><span style=\"mso-ascii-font-family:Calibri;mso-hansi-font-family:Calibri;mso-bidi-font-family:
                Calibri;color:black;mso-themecolor:text1;mso-ansi-language:EN-US\">For PM10, the
                hourly forecast data is compared to measured daily running mean values. </span></font></span><span style=\"mso-ansi-language:EN-US\"><font size=\"3\" style=\"font-weight: normal;\">Other pollutants like SO<sub style=\"\">2</sub> or CO are
                not included in this validation as they are constantly below threshold
                values.  The measurement data can be
                accessed freely from the ‘Hamburg Luftmessnetz.</font></span></h2></div>",
                "requireConfirm": false,
                "confirm": {
                    "text": "",
                    "color": "#ffffff",
                    "transparency": 0
                },
                "showOption": false,
                "confirmEverytime": true,
                "contentVertical": "top",
                "size": {
                    "mode": "wh",
                    "wh": {
                        "w": 1500,
                        "h": 900
                    }
                },
                "background": {
                    "mode": "color",
                    "image": null,
                    "type": "fill",
                    "fileName": "No%20file%20chosen",
                    "color": "#ffffff",
                    "transparency": 0
                },
                "button": {
                    "color": "#518dca",
                    "transparency": 0,
                    "text": "OK"
                }
            }
```

}

Comment: Run your JSON in a validator. Also, try a small, simple JSON test in whatever you're using to put the JSON in HTML.

Comment: Are you actually writing *JSON*, or just an object literal?  Please update this to a runnable code snippet which shows specifically what you're building.